# PowerShell script for System state backups of domain controller not working

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hello I am trying to get an automated backup for my domain controller to a network share using a script and windows task scheduler - our domain controller is windows server 2008r2

this is the code for the script i have written as seen below, however when i run the scrip it does create the folder on the network share but fails to initiate the system state backup power shell returns this error when i run the script.

any suggestions on what i can do to resolve this issue? i am also rather new to powershell so there many be a much easier way of going about it.

many thanks

Gordon

```
wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2004 Microsoft Corp.

ERROR - One of the parameters or options specified is invalid: [quiet].
See the syntax below.

Syntax: WBADMIN START SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP
-backupTarget:<VolumeName>
[-quiet]

Description:  Creates a system state backup of the local computer and stores
it on the location specified.
To use this command, you must be a member of the Backup Operators group
or Administrators group.

Parameters:
-backupTarget  Specifies the location where you want to store the backup.
            The storage location requires a drive letter or a GUID-based
            volume of the format: \\?\Volume{GUID}.

-quiet         Runs the command with no prompts to the user.

Example:
WBADMIN START SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP -backupTarget:f:
```

---

```
#adds windows server backup powershell snapin
Add-Pssnapin windows.serverbackup

#gets date
$date = Get-Date -Format dd.MM.yyyy 

#declares backup location and adds date
$backdir = ("\\backupserver\bpdbackups\DC\$date")

#makes backup directory on network share
mkdir $backdir | out-null 

#runs system statebackup
wbadmin start systemstatebackup -backupTarget:$backdir -[quiet]

#sends and email at the nd of the process

$smtp = "192.168.xxx.xxx"  
$from = "Domain Controller <support@domain.com>"  
$to = "Network Admin <network.helpxxx@xxx.com>"   
$body = "The backup operation has been successfully done! Date: $date"  
$subject = "Backup on $date"  

#Send an Email to User   
send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -From $from -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body -   BodyAsHtml  

write-host "Backup Successful"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so you have a couple of problems here. Firstly square brackets around a command line switch indicates that it is *optional* and should not be included. Secondly I think you need to enclose the string variable since you are not calling a powershell applet.

Try changing:

```
wbadmin start systemstatebackup -backupTarget:$backdir -[quiet]
```

to

```
wbadmin start systemstatebackup -backupTarget:"$backdir" -quiet
```